# request with list of id's for many to many relationship in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

What is the correct way of implementing the following api with django and django-rest-framework. First the model

**Model**

```
def ChatModel(models.Model):
   users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=ChatUser)
```

**Response**

The desired response when getting this model where the many to many relationship is presented with a nested serializer:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "gossip",
    "users": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "George"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Jerry"
        }  
    ]         
  }
]
```

The request is the critical part: Have the api receive a list of primary keys and create the user -> chat relationship in the backend.

**Request**

```
{
  "title": "gossip",
  "users": [1,2]
}
```

So how do I allow for such a request to create an object with a many to many relationship.

**Edit**

I've been trying to implement this using a `ChatRequestSerializer` class that makes users field something like this

```
 users = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=User.objects.all()))
```

and handle creating the relationships by overriding the `create` method of the serializer. This doesn't work because it throws the error: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: This question is more like: I have *this* and I want *that*. But the main part related to *how* I am doing this is missing. What you tried till now?

Comment: I've edited my question to explain what I did so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested serializer:

```
class NestedUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        readonly_fields = ('name',)


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = NestedUserSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta(object):
        model = models.Parent
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'users')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_ids = {u['id'] for u in validated_data.pop('users', [])}
        parent = super(ParentSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        # create users here
        return parent
```

The code is not tested. But I hope it will demonstrate my idea.

Please note that input should look like this:

```
{
    "title": "gossip",
    "users": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
}
```

Also you can check this answer: [django rest framework nested fields with multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639690/django-rest-framework-nested-fields-with-multiple-models/36679224#36679224)

Comment: The input is malformed, with two `id` keys.

Comment: Input example fixed.

Comment: The OP wanted the request payload as below:
{
  "title": "gossip",
  "users": [1,2]
}

But your example is different from what the OP wanted.